# I would like to concatanate different rows in another column where given 2 criterias are met?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13920 | APPLE | TRUE | 13920-13921-13924-13925 |
| 13921 | APPLE | TRUE | 13920-13921-13924-13925 |
| 13922 | ORANGE |  |  |
| 13923 | LEMON |  |  |
| 13924 | APPLE | TRUE | 13920-13921-13924-13925 |
| 13925 | APPLE | TRUE | 13920-13921-13924-13925 |
| 13927 | BANANA | TRUE | 13927-13928 |
| 13928 | BANANA | TRUE | 13927-13928 |

I need a formula that will bring me the results in column D.

When C1 is "TRUE", It will look for B1 Value (in this case APPLE) and search all the Apples in column B and concatanate all the corresponding Column A values in D1 . If Column C is not true than it will bring blank .

The formula I need is moreorless like SUMIFS funtion, only it will not sum , but will concatanate

And I will copy this formula in other rows in column D .

This can be either a formula or a VBA Code.

Answer (score 4):

Without Lambda, and using a Table with Structured References:
*(by using a Table, when you enter the formula in the first cell of Column 4, it will propagate to the entire column)*

```
=IF(
    [@Column3] = TRUE,
    TEXTJOIN(
        "-",
        ,
        FILTER([Column1], [Column2] = [@Column2])
    ),
    ""
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could try:

```
=MAP(B1:B8,C1:C8,LAMBDA(s,b,IF(b,TEXTJOIN("-",,FILTER(A1:A8,B1:B8=s)),"")))
```

Or, a little less verbose:

```
=MAP(B1:B8,C1:C8,LAMBDA(s,b,TEXTJOIN("-",,REPT(A1:A8,(B1:B8=s)*b))))
```

Answer (score 1):

For a VBA solution, please try the next code:

```
Sub ExtractAFruits()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastr As Long, i As Long, arr, arrRet, dict As Object
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary sheet
  lastr = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row
  
  arr = sh.Range("A2:C" & lastr).Value2  'place the range in an array for faster processing
  ReDim arrRet(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1) 'reDim the final array, to return concatenation in
  
  'load the dictionary with unique keys:
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If Trim(arr(i, 3)) = True Then
        dict(arr(i, 2)) = dict(arr(i, 2)) & "-" & arr(i, 1)
    End If
  Next i
  
  'place the necressary concatenated strings in arrRet
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If dict.Exists(arr(i, 2)) Then
        arrRet(i, 1) = Mid(dict(arr(i, 2)), 2)
    Else
        arrRet(i, 1) = ""
    End If
  Next i
  
  'drop arrRet content at once:
  sh.Range("D2").Resize(UBound(arrRet), 1).Value2 = arrRet
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Power Query solution:

```js
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"A", type text}, {"B", type text}, {"C", type logical}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([C] = true)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"C"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"B"}, {"D", each Text.Combine([A], "-"), type text}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source, {"B"}, #"Grouped Rows", {"B"}, "Table1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table1", {"D"}, {"D"})
in
    #"Expanded Table1"
```